# How to create a command that will allow a value and range at the same time

Tags: command, ibm-midrange

Not sure how to call it but I'm creating a command (CRTCMD) to compile it.
I wanted to achieve this in my command when F4 is pressed:

```
Test . . . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          1-8, *ALL
```

I tried all of this but it will either have an error or the desired outcome is wrong.

```
PARM KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(06) RSTD(*YES) + 
      PROMPT('Test') VALUES(*ALL *RANGE(1 8))
```

```
PARM KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(06) RSTD(*YES) +
      PROMPT('Test') VALUES(*ALL *RANGE 1 8)
```

```
PARM KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(06) RSTD(*YES) +
      PROMPT('Test') VALUES(*ALL 1-8)
```

```
PARM KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(06) +
      PROMPT('Test') RANGE(1 8)
```

```
PARM KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(06) RSTD(*YES) +
      PROMPT('Test')VALUES(*ALL) RANGE(1 8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `RANGE` and `SPCVAL` like below

- `RANGE` will restrict values to a range
- `SPCVAL` keyword will make special value `*ALL` available, `0` will be sent to the program

```
   PARM       KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(6) RANGE(1 8) +
         SPCVAL((*ALL 0)) PROMPT('Test')
```

`*ALL` can be used as default

```
   PARM       KWD(TEST) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(6) DFT(*ALL) RANGE(1 8) +
         SPCVAL((*ALL 0)) PROMPT('Test')
```

This is what I get :

```
Test . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   *ALL          1-8, *ALL
```